# Mock class to return By Reference in VB

Tags: vb.net, nunit, moq

Let me have class like this:

```
Public Class MyClass
    Implements IMyClass

    Public Function GetSomething(firstParameter As String, secondParameter As String, ByRef thirdParameter As String) As Boolean Implements IMyClass.GetSomething
        thirdParameter = _secondDependency.GetSomething(firstParameter, thirdParameter)
        Return True
    End Function

    'rest of class
```

Now in my test I am using NUnit and Moq lib and want to setup this mocked class

```
_mockMyClass.Setup(
            Function(myClass) myClass.GetSomething(It.IsAny(Of String), It.IsAny(Of String), It.IsAny(Of String))).Returns(True)
```

But I do not know how to setup thirdParameter to be set to some string I define, since it is passed by reference and I do not know how to do that with moq. I want to do this without changing the mocked class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I came with this which does the work:

```
_mockMyClass.
            Setup(Function(myClass) myClass.GetSomething(It.IsAny(Of String), It.IsAny(Of String), It.IsAny(Of String))).
            Callback(
                Sub(firstParameter As String, secondParameter As String, ByRef thirdParameter As String)
                    thirdParameter = "someString"
                End Sub).
```

It should be noted that this works in Moq 4.8+

Answer (score 0):

I've never done this but, based on the two minutes of web searching and reading I just did, it looks like you need to do this:

```vb
var str = It.IsAny(Of String)

_mockMyClass.Setup(
            Function(myClass) myClass.GetSomething(It.IsAny(Of String), It.IsAny(Of String), str)).Returns(True)
```

That's based on the C# example provided [here](https://im5tu.io/article/2020/11/using-moq-with-ref-in-and-out-parameters-in-c/). VB's `ByRef` is equivalent to C#'s `ref`.

Comment: My bad, I meant "some string I define", not Any string. Tnks for the answer tho, I have edited the question.